# Uso de Scopes con Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Necesito ayuda con un scope, necesito mostrar los productos que no estén en mi la lista de descuentos para irlos añadiendo.

Estoy intentando con este codigo:

```
scope :without_discount, -> (id_params)  {Producto.includes(:detalleld).where.not(:detalleld => { listaid: id_params })}
```

Y no me esta mostrando todos los productos sino que me muestra solo aquellos productos que están en otras listas de descuento mas no los que no están asociados a ninguna lista.

Comment: Intenta modificar la pregunta para que sea más fácil de leer. Si está todo en una linea es muy difícil de leer y obtendrás menos respuestas. El modo de vista previa te ayuda a saber como quedará el mensaje.

Comment: LuisC solucionaste el problema?

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo haría de la siguiente forma si partimos de la premisa que un producto solo puede estar en una lista a la vez. (Si no fuera así, habría que cambiar irse a una estructura [polymorphic](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) )

Un modelo Producto con los atributos que necesites y otro Lista que tiene muchos (o uno) productos

```
# producto.rb
class Producto 
 belongs_to: lista
end

# lista.rb
class Lista
 has_many: productos
end
```

De esta forma, tu scope sería mucho más fácil

```
scope :without_discount, -> (id_params) {Producto.includes(:detalleld).where.not(:detalleld => { lista_id: id_params })}
```

donde lista_id es un atributo (automático cuando se crea la migración de producto) del modelo Producto que indica si el producto pertenece a una lista.

Un par de observaciones:

- Ojo con los **plurales** en español! Recuerda que todo lo que se salga de añadir una 's' al final puedes indicarlo en el fichero pluralizations.rb. Más info en http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#pluralization
- Cuidado con los **includes** en los scopes que las querys se te pueden ir de las manos. Recomiendo la gem Bullet (https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) en desarrollo que ayuda a detectarlas y eliminarlas.